# Multiple Delete Using Checkbox in Laravel 5.4

Tags: checkbox, laravel-5.4

I am very new with Laravel. I am creating a project with data pagination. I successfuly made the CRUD work (thanks to the tutorials) but I am stock on how to delete multiple rows selected using checkbox. I tried to search around but I cannot find a very solid answer. I only found this sample using Javascript but I'm stock on the part where the JS script passes the variable to my controller. Here is my proble and I hope someone can help me. Sorry for my bad english.

```
Blade Page
                        @foreach ($it_equipments as $key => $d)
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkitem" value="{{ $d->id }}"></td>
                        <td>{{ $d->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $d->article }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $d->date_acquired }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $d->unit_measure }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $d->unit_value }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $d->onhand_qty }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $d->tot_value }}</td>
                        <td>
                             <div class="btn-group">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-del">Remove</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                                        <li><b>Balance/ Card Quantity:</b> {{ $d->bal_card_qty }}</li>
                                        <li><b>Drop Quantity:</b> {{ $d->drop_qty }}</li>
                                        <li><b>Drop Value:</b> {{ $d->drop_value }}</li>
                                        <li><b>Remarks:</b> {{ $d->remarks }}</li>
                                    </ul>
                             </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn btn-success">Action</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-successs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                                    <li><a href="{{ url('getEdit_inv',array($d->id)) }}">Edit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{ url('postDelete_inv',[$d->id]) }}"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this inventory entitled: {{ $d->article }} ?')">Delete</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="{{ url('postDelete_inv_selected',[$d->id]) }}"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete all selected rows?')">Delete Selected</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                             </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Script (Where I can't find where or how to connect it to my controller)

```
 <script>
$('#delsel').click(function()
{
    var id = $('.checkitem:checked').map(function()
    {
        return $(this).val()
    })
    .get().join(' ')
    $.post('help.php', {id: id}, function(data))
    {
        viewdata()
    })
})
</script>
```

`Router

```
Route:: `get('/postDelete_inv_selected/{id}','InvController@postDelete_inv_selected');`
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem - in your `Route...` you have `/postDelete_inv_selected/{id}` but in your JS code you never use this routing but instead you use `help.php`...

You should use something like this (i do it from head - not tested it)

```
Route::get('/postDelete_inv_selected', 'InvController@postDelete_inv_selected');
```

I remove "id" parameter at the end of your routing (becouse js `$.post` method send this parameter in request body, not in link). Read `id` parameter inside controller (using `request('id')` ). And in JS you should use something like this (may be adding some prefix - it depends of your routing and eventually [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)):

```
$.post('postDelete_inv_selected',...
```

Read more about [laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

I also suggest to change name from 'id' to 'ids' becouse it will contains many id's - it alswo will be better to not join them into one string but send as json array

Comment: Sir can you check this please...                                                            
var ids = $('.checkitem:checked').map(function()
            {
                 return $(this).val()
            })
            .get().join(' ')
            $.post('postDelete_inv_selected', {id: ids}, function(data))
            {
            viewdata() //where is this viewdata() going?
            })

Comment: here's my controller                                                                                               public function postDelete_inv_selected(Request $id)

    {
        $id = $request-> Input::get ( 'chkrow' );
        ITEquip::where('id',$id)->delete();
        return back()->with('success','Selected rows has been removed.');
    }

Comment: 1. @ResnefImmatong Why you don't run and check?
2. I sugest change `post(..., {id: ids}, ...`  to `post(..., {ids: ids}...` an same in controler: `id` change to `ids`

Comment: This is bad `postDelete_inv_selected(Request $id) { $id = $request-> Input::get ( 'chkrow' )...` it shoud be something like this: `postDelete_inv_selected() { $id = request('ids')...` (eventualli some json pasing will be needed)

Comment: already solved it...$.ajax({
                           url: "/postDelete_inv_selected",
                           type: "get",
                           data: {'id':id}
                        });

Comment: If my hint's help you, pleas click on the upper gray triangle and/or on the big 'check' under this answers points (on the left side at the begining of above answer)